# telerik grid sorting: settings of grids are lost after sorting

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, telerik-grid

I've a grid with "cellAction" event, like:

```
@(Html.Telerik().Grid(Model)
        .Name("Grid")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            //columns
        })
        .cellAction(cell => { 
               cell.HtmlAttributes["onClick"] = "cellSelected(event)";})
```

sorting by DataBinding like:

```
.DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding.Ajax().Select("_Sorting", "Grid"))
```

and server side:

```
[GridAction]
public ActionResult _Sorting()
{
    return View(new GridModel<Order>
    {
        Data = GetOrders()
    });
}
```

the problem is, the cellSelected event works only before sorting.
after i sorting this not invoked.
seem that settings of grid lost after sorting.
why ?

Comment: this seems like a bug, try asking on the telerik forum ... my guess is that after the sorting the table markup is regenerated and the click event binding is lost...

Comment: I think @dakait is right.. try to rebind click event after Grid Rebind..